# Randomize Posts. Skip the first post in ascending order

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'd like to randomize a set of posts (custom post type), but ignore the first post all together.

Here's the code I thought would work:

```
$featured_content_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'       => 'feature',
  'offset'          => 1,
  'posts_per_page'  => 10,
  'order'           => 'ASC',
  'orderby'         => 'rand'
) );
```

Without the `orderby` the post I want skipped over is ignored, but as soon as I add the random order it adds it back into the mix.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are different ways of achieving this. Simplest way I could imagine is as below:

```
$featured_content_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'       => 'feature',
  'offset'          => 1,
  'posts_per_page'  => 10,
  'order'           => 'ASC'
 ) );

shuffle( $featured_content_query );    //PHP function to randomise posts array
```

You can then continue to use `$featured_content_query` as usual!

Comment: This is an efficient, straight forward way to achieve the goal. You could come up with 100 ways to exclude the most recent post from the query, but each of those will require at least one extra WP_Query (and therefore a DB call). With the solution by @sri you have an easy way to include your objective in one query then randomize.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for another answer and stumbled on this, thought i could help.

If you looking to exclude the most recent post(s) you may be able to use [wp_get_recent_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to retrieve the ID(s), and then use `'post__not_in' => array(#,#)` in your WP_Query to exclude those resent posts.

Tested this a little and found this to work for getting ONE post to be excluded. I think you could parse the results differently to get more than just on ID if you so desired.

```
$recent = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>$type,'numberposts'=>'1'));
$recentID[] = $recent[0]['ID']; // this creates an array of one

$args = array(
     'post_type'        => $type
    ,'post_staus'       => 'publish'
    ,'post__not_in'     => $recentID // array()
```